# How to select filetypes in bash script or perl and act based on the type

Tags: bash, file

For the moment, ignore any issues with the specific file type used here as an example only.

Given a directory with multiple types of files, like a README file in markdown format, git version control files, PEM keys, and other random file types, what's the best way, in terms of portability or even readability, to select ONLY the PEM keys in the directory and move those over to an arbitrary location?

One possible option was to use the `file` tool, which returns the file type. For example:

```
$ file randomly-named-file
randomly-named-file: PEM RSA private key
```

#### Essentially, what's the best way, in terms of portability or readability, to create a test something like the following pseudo "code"?

```
if file $1 is PEM
mv $1 /some/other/dir
fi
```

---

Bash is preferred; though, perl solution is acceptable if necessary.

The original question stemmed from use on a Mac OSX platform with high use-case of and needed portability between Linux (RHEL-based, Gentoo) platforms.

The `file` version is 5.31, supporting `-print0`, for what it's worth.

It might be worth noting, that the `file` tool is just the obvious first choice I thought of.  It does NOT have to be using that tool if other portable solutions are available.

Comment: "The best" is opinion-based. Do you want _readable_, or _fast_, or _portable_, or a combination of those? Or maybe something else? Also, if you want it in bash, why tag _awk_ and _perl_?

Comment: I've updated the question to include "perl" as a possible alternative if it's more readable or portable.  I'll update the question with that definition, too. :)

Comment: Which version of `file`? Do you have one that supports `-print0`?

Comment: BTW, could you describe the value your magic database provides with `file -I randomly-named-file` when it's a PEM key?

Comment: My `file` doesn't recognize `-I`, but with `-i` it says `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`.

Comment: ...and, again, does it support `-0`?

Comment: file version 5.31 on a Macbook Pro; I'm used to using Linux, so not sure what provides `file` on here.  Also, worth mentioning, that's one obvious possible tool to use to test.  I'm not saying that it _has_ to be using the `file` tool.  The magic database provides the following output when using the `-I` flag on a PEM key: `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`.

Comment: `file` uses libmagic. Pretty much anything else you use for the job will be libmagic-based as well (and have about the same characteristics, backending into the same database to recognize signatures), unless you just go grepping for the specific PEM header; it's far from perfect (so very, *very* far from perfect), but it's also the ubiquitous tool for the job in the open-source world.

Comment: It *does* support `-print0`, btw.

Comment: On *my* platform, the local `magic` database doesn't have a PEM entry, so output is just "ASCII text", not "PEM RSA private key". Makes testing a little tricky. That said, my answer as-amended appears to be going through all the right steps when run with `bash -x`, such that it would have the desired behavior somewhere libmagic *did* know how to recognize PEM files.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what's your platform? I'm seeing same output for my Mac OSX version of `file` as well as on a Gentoo VM as I described in my earlier comments.

Comment: MacOS High Sierra, using `/usr/bin/file` (not a Homebrew or MacPorts replacement). My test data for this purpose consisted of the contents of https://github.com/fcwu/docker/tree/master/integration/fixtures/https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable implementation (subject to all the usual limitations of libmagic) requiring `file -0` might look like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh; requires bash-specific syntax.

while IFS= read -r -d '' filename && read -r type; do
  type=${type#": "}
  if [[ $type = *"PEM RSA private key"* ]]; then
    printf 'Found file: %q\n' "$filename"
  fi
done < <(file -0 -- *)
```

The `-0` argument tells `file` to print a NUL after each filename; `IFS= read -r -d ''` reads up to the first NUL, so it thus consumes only the filename, whereas `read -r type` consumes the rest of each line.

This makes it possible to disambiguate names from types in the list, even if those names contain colons, newlines, or other surprising characters. If you didn't have `-0`, you'd need to start a separate copy of `file` for each file you wanted to test, with the associated performance hit.

Comment: Absolutely, I try to avoid the `/bin/sh` shell on OSX.  Portability fix; thanks :)

Comment: maybe prepend `OLDFS=$IFS` or is that not an issue as long as it's only declared within the `while` loop?

Comment: @ILMostro_7, huh? It's not just scoped to the `while` loop, but to the individual `read` command. `foo=bar somecommand` assigns `foo` the value `bar` (in the environment) only for the duration of `somecommand`. (It *doesn't* have that assignment in effect during expansions preparatory to the command's execution, which is a common source of confusion). Thus, that assignment is set only when reading `filename`, and not when reading `type`.

Comment: yeah, I meant if it's part of the script, additional commands will be affected by the changed IFS unless I'm missing something and it's limited in scope.

Comment: @ILMostro_7, as I said, it's scoped **only to that one `read` command**, and does not affect any other commands whatsoever.

Comment: @ILMostro_7, ...you can test this yourself at a command line with a simple copy/paste: `IFS=abc read foo <<<"meh"; printf '%q=%q\n' IFS "$IFS"` won't show `abc` as the value unless that's what it was beforehand.

Comment: ...compare that to `IFS=abc; read foo <<<"meh"`, where the new IFS value *does* carry over to other commands -- but we're intentionally not doing that here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CharlesDuffy. One thing to add would be the `cp -r` command within the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

If, for some reason, you cannot rely on `file`, you can try the using `head` to inspect the file for the PEM file standard header, like so:

```
for file in ./*; do
    echo "Examining file: $file"
    first_line=$(head -n 1 "$file")
    if [ "$first_line" = "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----" ]; then
        echo "Found PEM file"
        mv example.pem /my/arbitrary/dir
    fi
done
```

I created a small directory with the following test files:

```
$ ls
pretend.pdf example.pem script.sh   text_file.txt
```

Running the script against this directory gives the following results:

```
$ ./script.sh 
Examining file: ./pretend.pdf
Examining file: ./example.pem
Found PEM file
Examining file: ./script.sh
Examining file: ./text_file.txt
```

Comment: Fair is fair.  I fixed it.

Comment: Yup. Good answer as-amended.

Comment: Might be worth editing the answer to act upon multiple files, rather than testing a single file.  Although, if it's added to a script it would do the trick. :)

Comment: By the way, awesome alternative to `file` and probably more portable, as `head` is more likely to be included than `file` by default, IMHO.

Comment: For what its worth, I developed that script on MacOS Sierra

Comment: BTW, you could make this substantially faster (when running with a large number of files) with `IFS= read -r first_line <"$file"` instead of invoking an external copy of `head` in a subshell for each file you loop over. (With that change, the only external command --
 not built into the shell -- would be `mv`, and that's of course only invoked when an actual match is found).

Comment: Might also `[ -f "$file" ] || continue` at the top of the loop to skip directories and other non-file contents.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  These are fair points but I went for readability first =)  If you wish to edit my answer, be my guest.

Comment: For some reason some of the files don't get returned, even though the headers are the same as of those that DO get returned as the expect file type; `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.  Maybe the checks should be on the text only, ignoring the dashes and possible whitespace.

Comment: @ILMostro_7, if you run the script with `bash -x`, what does the test command running for those lines where the files aren't returnedlook like in practice? I wouldn't be surprised if maybe your files ended in DOS newlines (`$'\r'` characters); if that's the case, then `first_line=${first_line%$'\r'}` would trim them. If you want to trim leading and trailing whitespace, you could also use the `read` line I gave above, but make sure `IFS` defines the whitespace characters to be ignored (ie. `IFS=$' \t\r'` or such) instead of being `IFS=`.

Comment: the test returns the first line correctly, AFAICT, but the next step gets skipped, for lack of a better term.  I do see an additional whitespace at the end of the first line; I don't think it's DOS newlines, tbh.

Comment: I'd need a better description -- not clear what's meant by "skipped" in this context.